# full_join in R with NA as wildcard to match any value in the other data.frame

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I'm looking for a way to make dplyr'r full_join treat NA in the "by" columns as wildcards for joining, i.e. that a NA will match any value in the corresponding column of the other data frame and join the corresponding rows.

EXAMPLE: I have several data.frames in R, defining certain product characteristics, some of which depend on finer-grained features, others only on the high-level product class:

```
x = data.frame(class = c("A", "B", "B", "C"), flags = c(NA, "individual", "group", NA), interest = c(0.04, 0.03, 0.02, 0.05));x
y = data.frame(class = c("A", "A", "B", "B", "C"), flags = c("individual", "group", "individual", "group", NA), costs = c(0.05, 0.025, 0.03, 0.02, 0.01));y
```

```
> x
  class      flags interest
1     A       <NA>     0.04
2     B individual     0.03
3     B      group     0.02
4     C       <NA>     0.05
> y
  class      flags costs
1     A individual 0.050
2     A      group 0.025
3     B individual 0.030
4     B      group 0.020
5     C       <NA> 0.010
```

Now I want to join those two to create one table of product characteristics, but I want the NA in the 'flags' column to match any value in the flags column of the other data.frame, resulting in the following joint data.frame:

```
> expected
  class      flags interest costs
1     A individual     0.04 0.050
2     A      group     0.04 0.025
3     B individual     0.03 0.030
4     B      group     0.02 0.020
5     C       <NA>     0.05 0.010
```

Unfortunately, full_join only matches by exact string match, so the  in the flags column will not match any of the values ("group", "partner", "individual") of the flags column of the other data frame:

```
> actual = full_join(x,y, by=c("class","flags"));actual
  class      flags interest costs
1     A       <NA>     0.04    NA
2     B individual     0.03 0.030
3     B      group     0.02 0.020
4     C       <NA>     0.05 0.010
5     A individual       NA 0.050
6     A      group       NA 0.025
```

How can I make full_join treat NA as matching any string (rather than matching only other NAs)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can join only on the `class` column and then filter:

```
library(dplyr)
x |>
  full_join(y, by = "class", relationship = "many-to-many") |>
  filter(flags.x == flags.y | is.na(flags.x) | is.na(flags.y)) |>
  mutate(flags = coalesce(flags.x, flags.y)) |>
  select(class, flags, interest, costs)
#   class      flags interest costs
# 1     A individual     0.04 0.050
# 2     A      group     0.04 0.025
# 3     B individual     0.03 0.030
# 4     B      group     0.02 0.020
# 5     C       <NA>     0.05 0.010
```

Comment: Thanks, that works very well. Although I wonder why one has to emulate a wildcard matching by manual filtering. I would imagine that this could be a core feature of the *_join function...

Comment: Even in SQL, this is pretty much how you'd do it. It's just that in SQL the filtering can be part of the join clause.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if you could try a different approach by joining on non-`NA` columns. For example, `split` your data.frame by each row, then select the columns that are not `NA`, and use those to join with the second data.frame. For `class` "A" that has `NA` for `flags`, it will do a join based on `class` only; while for `class` "B", it will join on both `class` and `flags`.

```
library(tidyverse)

x %>%
  split(seq(nrow(.))) %>%
  map_dfr(~.x %>%
             select_if(!is.na(.)) %>%
             inner_join(y, .))
```

**Output**

```
  class      flags costs interest
1     A individual 0.050     0.04
2     A      group 0.025     0.04
3     B individual 0.030     0.03
4     B      group 0.020     0.02
5     C       <NA> 0.010     0.05
```